# Using two MVC applications with one database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a MVC website with SQL Server database. The website consists of two web applications: actual MVC application and admin CMS for the website.

I would like to host my website under www.mydomain.com and the CMS under cms.mydomain.com. Both application will use same database.

Are there any problems in hosting my project this way?

Comment: I've managed a website affiliate system where a single database was used by a number of separate eCommerce applications and a "super admin" application with no issues at all. That was using EF and MVC3, with a steady flow of transactions on a fairly standard webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problems at all. Make sure, your database is accessible for both apps.

Databases are designed to be consumed by different apps. That is why most of relational databases support multi-threading, transactions, locks etc. All this stuff is needed to enforce data consistency. So, it is normal application architecture.

Comment: Sure, the applications and database are in the same server. So I will give each one a login and that's it ... I hope ... :-)

Comment: @MDMoura, yep. good luck. Databases are designed to be consumed by different apps. That is why most of relational databases support multi-threading, transactions, locks etc. All this stuff is needed for data consistency. So, it is normal application architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If sharing of the same data between both application is important i.e. you want the data to be shared between applications - than you have to use the same database. It'll slow down processing, but if it's the requirement, then you have to.
that's why u can access your same data of your fb account from your mobile application and also from web browser

Comment: The problem the MVC application for the website is multilanguage and it has become quite big. The cms was as an AREA of the MVC website but I would like to move it to a different application also so that the maintenance of the two applications can be independent. Bot application share one class library where I have the service layer. In the future my idea is to turn this class library into a Web API and make both applications to access the web api. The CMS is not used intensive ... Is more for the team to manage content.

Comment: That'll be a bit of work to separate services into a separate project referenced by both MVC projects. But entirely doable. And still no issues with single database for both applications.

Comment: That is already done ... I have 3 class libraries: Core, Data, Services and the MVC website. In Services I am using Query/Reply and Command pattern. So each one is a specific action ... So basically all I am doing is separating the "Front End" in two different applications. I also need an application that sends emails know and then and I am considering placing that in the CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Should be no issue. I've done application and added CMS later. Both using the same database. Even better, my app uses EF, CMS uses NHibernate. No issues yet. Was a bit fiddly to set things up, but in productions it runs fine.

Comment: What do you mean a bit fiddle to set things up? I will use EF in CMS and EF + Dapper in the website application.